# Holomorphic connectedness in several complex variables

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

**Let $\Omega$ be domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Suppose we have taken two distinct points from $\Omega$. Does there exist a domain $U$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that there is a holomorphic function from $U$ to $\Omega$ whose range contains these two points?**

I tried to prove the identity theorem in several complex variables. Then my mind gave me that above question.

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaking the question, but put in this way, an almost trivial answer is $$ \Bbb C\ni\zeta\mapsto (1-\zeta)z_1 + \zeta z_2 \in \Bbb C^n$$ does the job for every sufficiently large $U\subset \Bbb C$ such that $U\supset [0,1]$ (*de facto* you can take $U$ as the inverse image of $\Omega$ respect to the shown linear map).

Comment: We can easily deduce this for the convex domains. But What's for general domains?@DanieleTampieri

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out: simply stated, you need a holomorphic curve joining two points of a general (not necessarily convex) arcwise connected domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb C^n$. Fix two points $z_0$, $z_1$ in $\Omega$. Then
there exists a curve $\alpha : [0, 1] \to \Omega$ connecting these points. Using the Weierstrass approximation theorem there is a polynomial map $P : [0, 1] \to\Omega$ with
$P(0) = z_0$ and $P(1) = z_1$. Then it is easy to choose a simply connected domain
$D\subset\mathbb C$, $[0, 1]\subset D$, such that $P(D)\subset\Omega$. By the Riemann mapping theorem we can conclude that $z_0$, $z_1$
lie on an analytic disc $\phi : \mathbb D \to \Omega$.

Even more, this is also true for complex manifolds according to a result by Winkelmann.

Answer (score 2):

If $\Omega$ is Stein than for any discrete closed sequence $(x_n)\subset \Omega$ there is a proper holomorphic map from the unit disk $f:\Delta\rightarrow\Omega$ that passes throughout these points, i.e. $(x_n)\subset f(\Delta)$.

For example see:
*Discs in Stein manifolds containing given discrete sets. Math.Z. 239 (2002) no.4, 683-702,*  by Drinovec Drnovšek

Comment: What if $\Omega$ is not Stein?

Comment: It also holds for any open connected set (except you lose the property of being proper). For example take a real analitic curve that connects two points and take its tubular naighbourhood wihich is Stein (and then use the above result), or more simply just take the complexification of this real analyitic curve which is going to be an embeded disc (in a smal nbh of this curve).